# In Kotlin, how do I convert "CompletableFuture<Optional<T>>" to "Flow<T?>"?

Tags: kotlin, reactive-programming, kotlin-extension, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to convert a `CompletableFuture<Optional<T>>` to a `Flow<T?>`.  The extension function I'm trying to write is

```
fun <T> CompletableFuture<Optional<T>>.asFlowOfNullable(): Flow<T?> =
    this.toMono().map { (if (it.isPresent) it.get() else null) }.asFlow()
```

but it fails because `asFlow()` doesn't exist for nullable types, AFAICT based on its definition.

So, how do I convert `CompletableFuture<Optional<T>>` to `Flow<T?>`?

*Edit 1:*

Here's what I've come up with so far.  Feedback appreciated.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flowOf
import java.util.Optional
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture

fun <T> Optional<T>.orNull(): T? = orElse(null)

fun <T> CompletableFuture<Optional<T>>.asFlowOfNullable(): Flow<T?> = flowOf(this.join().orNull())
```

FYI, in my case, which is using Axon's Kotlin extension [`queryOptional`](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/extensions/kotlin#querygateway), I can now write this:

```
inline fun <reified R, reified Q> findById(q: Q, qgw: QueryGateway): Flow<R?> {
    return qgw.queryOptional<R, Q>(q).asFlowOfNullable()
}
```

I'll defer for a while creating a comment with the above pattern as the answer to allow for feedback.

*Edit 2:*
Since it was pointed out below that `asFlowOfNullable` in Edit 1 would block the thread, I'm going with this from @Joffrey for now:

```
fun <T> Optional<T>.orNull(): T? = orElse(null)

fun <T> CompletableFuture<Optional<T>>.asDeferredOfNullable(): Deferred<T?> = thenApply { it.orNull() }.asDeferred()
```

Edit 3:  credit to both @Tenfour04 & @Joffrey for their helpful input.  :)

Comment: In Kotlin, we usually don't use `Flow` to represent a single item. It's more natural to use a simple suspend function that returns the value. Why do you need a flow here?

Comment: Because I'm using Axon's Kotlin extension to call `QueryGateway.query<R,Q>(query:Q): CompletableFuture<R>` where there is only a single item or null.

Comment: @Joffrey see https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/extensions/kotlin#querygateway

Comment: That explains why you have a CompletableFuture, but not why you want to convert it to a Flow instead of a suspend function or Deferred.

Comment: Your code in Edit 1 will block the calling thread until completion because of the `join` call.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Regarding Edit 1:  yeah, that's what I was afraid after I thought about it for a while.

Comment: Regarding your edit 2, it would be interesting to see how you're using this helper function. If you're not passing around the deferred value, you will most likely `await()` it almost right away (suspending the coroutine), which means you could simply have used a suspending `await()` function on the `CompletableFuture` directly instead converting to `Deferred`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the below extensions, you need the `jdk8` coroutines library:

```groovy
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8:$1.5.0"
```

I'm not sure where the `asFlow()` function comes from that you're using, but here's a way I think would work without it. It seems a little odd to me to have a Flow of a single item, because it could just be a `suspend` function or if you need it as an object to pass around, a Deferred, which is intended for returning a single result and is therefore more analogous to a Future than a Flow.

```
fun <T> CompletableFuture<Optional<T>>.asFlowOfNullable(): Flow<T?> =
    flow { emit(await().orElse(null)) }
```

As a suspend function:

```
suspend fun <T> CompletableFuture<Optional<T>>.awaitNullable(): T? = 
    await().orElse(null))
```

As a deferred:

```
fun <T> CompletableFuture<Optional<T>>.asDeferredNullable(): Deferred<T?> =
    thenApply { it.orElse(null) }.asDeferred()
```

Comment: See my reply above for motivation.  I tried both of your samples, and got the following compile error:  `Kotlin: Unresolved reference: await`.  Am I missing some import?

Comment: `asFlow()` is coming from `import kotlinx.coroutines.reactive.asFlow`

Comment: @MatthewAdams You need the `kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8` library.

Comment: What are your thoughts about using `Deferred<T?>` versus a `Flow<T?>` that will only ever have a single value?

Comment: The Flow is awkward. The only case I can think of where it would make sense is you are passing it to some API that only accepts Flow. Even the Deferred has limited cases where it would make more sense than simply exposing a suspend function. You only need Deferred if you have multiple asynchronous actions going on at once that you need to coordinate.

Comment: @MatthewAdams `Deferred` is in essence a single deferred value, while a `Flow` doesn't tell much about whether it will produce 0, 1 or more values. I would seriously refrain from using `Flow` for a single value unless you want to use this flow in a place where you want to also accept or return other flows with potentially more values.

Comment: @Joffrey's explanation is good. When you have a Flow, you don't know how many results it will produce. It might be 0 or it might be theoretically infinite, in which case calling `collect()` on it will prevent any subsequent code in a coroutine from ever being reached.

Comment: Ok, as a result of this discussion, I've filed issue https://github.com/AxonFramework/extension-kotlin/issues/139.  I hope this goes somewhere.

Comment: @Joffrey How would you rewrite your "As Deferred" function as a `suspend fun`?

Comment: @MatthewAdams I'm not the author of this answer, but the suspending version is already provided by @Tenfour04. It's called `awaitNullable` in this answer. It does not return a `Deferred`, it just returns `T?` because the "asynchrony" is already expressed by the `suspend` modifier. On the other hand, if you convert the `CompletableFuture` to a `Deferred`, you don't need to suspend because you're just converting a future type into another immediately - there is nothing to wait for.

Comment: @MatthewAdams regarding the filed issue, it would be more appropriate for the API to expose `suspend` functions returning plain values (or Unit) rather than exposing functions with `Deferred` return types.

Comment: @Joffery agreed.  I must've missed @Tenfour04's `suspend` version -- I understand now.  I'll mention the use of `suspend` in the Axon github issue.  Thanks!

Comment: @Tenfour04 The maintainers of https://github.com/AxonFramework are open to improving https://github.com/AxonFramework/extension-kotlin based on issue https://github.com/AxonFramework/extension-kotlin/issues/139.  They've asked me if I'm willing to submit a PR for the changes.  I am, however, I still consider myself a Kotlin noob.  Would y'all be willing to help me with the PR so that I ensure that the Kotlin idioms are actually idiomatic?  You can email me at matthew@matthewadams.me to discuss.  Thanks!

Comment: @Joffrey StackOverflow wouldn't let me tag you also in the above comment.  Same question above is for you, too.  :)